# Fourier Transformation of Absolute Values to negative Powers

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

I consider the Fourier Transformation of an Absolute Value, i.e.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{ikx}}{|x|^{a/2}}dx,
$$

with $a \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$. I'm not able to find a solution for this integral. Does anybody know what the solution is or if an solution exists?

greetz

mike

Comment: You mean $a>2$? Because for $a\le 2$ the Lebesgue-integral does not even exist.

Comment: In my case $a$ is actually just an integer starting from one. But do you know how to find a solution for a>2?

Comment: I was wrong. The integral does not exist for any $a>0$. The function $x\mapsto |x|^{-a/2}$ is only locally integrable on $\mathbb R$ for $a < 2$. So, for $a\ge 2$ the Fourier transform does not even exist as a distribution. If $a < 2$ it is at least a distribution.